# jinja2 javascript block fadeout not working

Tags: javascript, jinja2

I believe this code should be working but it does not appear to be

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $('#email').change(function () {
      var len = $('#email').val().length;
      if (len > 0) {
          $("#user_accounts").fadeOut(1)
      } else {
          $("#user_accounts").fadeIn(1)

      }
  });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<!-- About Section -->
    <section id="about"  class="bg-light-gray">
        <div class="container">
```

I am trying to hide a div #user_accounts if an text input field contains any text.  There are no error messages when debugging and user_accounts is not fading.

here is the html i'm using

```
                        <br>
                        Add user to accounts: <input id='email' type="text" placeholder="user@email.com">
                        <br><br>
                        <div id="user_accounts">
                        {% for item in accounts %}
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="pull-left"><input type="checkbox" name="accounts" id="accounts" value="{{ item[0] }}" {% if item[0] not in muted %}checked{% endif %}>
                                    {{ item[0] }} - <span title="{{item[1]}}">{{item[1] | truncate(20, True) }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
```

Comment: First and foremost: don't use inline JS, put your JS in its own file, put that in your static assets dir, and then [load that using the `{% static .... %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/). Unless this is a partial/fragment associated with some particular object model, in which case: don't load that JS in the template at all, instead tell Django that your template has associated JS that should only be loaded once on page that uses your fragment, no matter how many instances are being templated in.

Comment: Check whether the script is loaded after the html ? If the script is coming prior to the html the $('#email') will not give any DOM element and won't work.